# How to find exact version selected by nuget for a PackageReference?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package

I can refer NuGet packages in .NET Core using

```
<PackageReference Include="ExamplePackage" Version="6.*" />
```

How to find the exact version of ExamplePackage used during the build?

Comment: Look in the obj/project.assets.json file. That lists the versions resolved and used. Or you can look at the build output if you enable diagnostic logging with MSBuild.

Comment: @MattWard Will try. Thanks.